# What does $releasever and $basearch mean here?

Tags: yum

```
[dag]
name=Dag RPM Repository for Red Hat Enterprise Linux
baseurl=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el$releasever/en/$basearch/dag
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

And when will `enabled=0` be useful? Why is there such an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both just yum variables which are automatically completed for you.

- `$releasever` is release version (RHEL 4, Centos 5, etc)
- `$basearch` is the base architecture (32bit, 64bit, etc)

`Enable = 0` will preventing you to use this repository.

Regards

Comment: I still don't know how's `$releasever` assigned ...

Comment: If i'm not mistaken it derives the $releasever value from the version number of the package configured as "distroverpkg" (actually, whatever "provides" that in RPM parlance) in /etc/yum.conf, and $basearch from a call to the operating
system's uname(2) function.

Comment: @TiZon you are right.

Comment: 'enabled' is useful is you want to do a one-off install of a package, but not use this repository for anything else.